# Trigger Image Creation from Input field's text

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, append

A user types words into an input field, after clicking the Go button, little images with file names that match the keywords pop up in a certain place in the hierarchy. I just wanted someone to double check this script to see if there's any bugs in it, as it doesn't appear to work. The input is a comma separated list, hence the trim.

```
$(".Go").live('click', function(){
    var words = [];
    jQuery.each(jQuery.trim(jQuery("#input").val()).split(","), function(index, value){
        words.push(jQuery.trim(value));
    });

    for(i=0; i > words.length(); i++){
        $('#Place').append('img').attr("src", words[i]+'.png');
    }
});
```

Thanks goes out to Femi, who formulated this script for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Here's a working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/c7u3N/) with various improvements.

The reasons your code won't work are:

- `i > words.length()` will always be false as you're initially setting it to `0`, that needs to be `<`.
- `length` is a property, not a function. Remove the brackets.
- Your syntax for appending a new `img`
  element just appends a string of
  'img'.  In order to use [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to append a new element like that, you'll need to use the overload that takes a function.
- Not strictly a bug, but there's a lot
  of unnecessary code in there. `split()`
  returns an array already, so looping
  through that array to put each array
  element into another array is
  redundant.  There's also no reason to
  new up the `words` array before
  assigning it.
- There's no particular reason to use
  [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) if you're not dynamically
  adding elements with a class of `go`.
  You could simply use [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/)
  instead.

**EDIT:**
In answer to the comments, here's how to [add the images to two different containers based on the word](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/VZ9jg/).

**EDIT 2:**
and to [add the image to a different container based on whether the 'word' is upper case, lower case, numbers or symbols (ie: none of the above!)](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/4V6CG/)

Comment: @Town - Thanks for the working demo!, i did need it to be live, so i made that tweak. It wasn't working at first, but then i saw that your fiddle was using 1.6, so i updated mine (1.5.2). If i wanted to check the contents of any entry in the words array for a particular string value, is there a way i could do that? The target #Place is different if the input is X, Y or Z.

Comment: @Jason: It should work fine with 1.5.2... it does with jsfiddle anyway.  You can certainly check the contents of `words[i]` within the loop, possibly using a [switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) and then setting a variable to use in place of `#place` when you call `append()`.  It depends on how many different permutations you've got.

Comment: @Town: I'm having difficulty setting up a switch statement, since i'm not very familiar with arrays. If i want to check if words[i] is either 'a,b,c,d, or e,' and if so, set the return target to a specific place, how would i do that? Should i make a new question for that?

Comment: @Jason: this is where it depends on how complex the matches are and how many different elements you want to add the images to.  For that scenario you describe there, I'd do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/VZ9jg/).  I've commented it up so it's a bit more clear.

Comment: @Town : I see what you mean, in which case, there are 4 possible target places. Lets say, one for lower case, one for upper case, one for numbers, and one for symbols. Sorry to be bothering you with this, but i am quite grateful for the help.

Comment: @Jason: Ah, now you're getting into regular expression territory - matching the _pattern_ that the 'word' follows rather than a straight text comparison.  I can't help right now but I might have a crack later if I don't find anything better to do ;)

Comment: @Jason: Actually, it appears I have nothing better to do, so [there you go](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/4V6CG/).  Symbols is tough - I've gone with _not letters or numbers_ but if you've got a particular set you want to match then you can define them.  Have a look at this [Introduction to Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Comment: @Town: i was just using lower/uppercase as an example of difference, but i am specifically after text comparisons as the number of expected keyword strings is rather finite, 46 to be precise, split between 4 'groups'.

Comment: @Jason: Haha! Worst. Example. Ever. ;) Okay, then a similar `if`/`else` but comparing to the contents of 4 arrays containing the words that are pertinent to each group.  It'll work, but it seems inefficient to me and I can't help but think there's a better way.  If I think of it I'll let you know :)

Comment: @Town : I finally got it to work, although the solution isn't that elegant. Using if ((words[i] == "Pw") | ...), i listed each appropriate value that should go to X place, then had 3 else-if following that -if statement, which covered the other places, using -or statements again to capture each appropriate value.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the condition has a couple typos

```
i > words.length()
```

This will never be true and `length` is a property. Should be:

```
for(i=0; i < words.length; i++)
```

Comment: Not sure what the +1 is for on this, it won't work.  `length` is a property, not a function. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Missed that one myself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely a typo there. Here's a good guide, with they typo corrected, to help you along with your script: http://jsfiddle.net/vkSQy/